# importing from module scope in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a pretty big typescript project with a tsconfig file containing this:

```
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "None",
```

and most if not all ts files are on this format

```
module Controllers {
  import Dispatcher = Dispatch.Dispatcher;
  export class ...
```

And I wonder if it is possible to use a more "normal"(in my eyes) way of importing classes/files without breaking anything old?

Basically I want to be able to do this style of import

```
import { Parameters } from "./GUI";
```

and I can't really figure out how to do that if it is at all possible